# How do I kill a particular chrome tab/process

Tags: c#, google-chrome, windows-services

I am writing a windows service that I would like to run as a scheduled task. 
On Start I want it to read in the chrome processes and kill any that have a particular url..

I can get the processes using

```
var list = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
```

but after that I am stumped..

The MainWindowTitle of each process is "" and the MainWindowHandle is 0 so doesn't help me.

I have read numerous posts related to this and it seems there is no api into chrome so am I wasting my time?

Any help appreciated
J

Comment: If you can't find the way to do it through the api you might consider do something through autoit: http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score 3):

If you look at spy++ you can see that you can find root windows that do have their Caption set to the html page title.  Also a child window is the url bar so if you enum the child windows of all the chrome windows you uld be able to find it.

sho[image: Spy++ Chome INfo]

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to do this, I wouldn't recommend it. Injecting yourself in to other processes and reading their contents can cause unpleasant behavior and is hard to get completely correct, but if I was going to try this, I would use the UI automation tools provided by MS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx), or White (http://teststack.github.io/White/). Those are going to be the best bets.